# nth-child recipe based on dynamic PHP variable

Tags: php, css

I have 12 divs, one for each month. I am then setting a PHP variable with a "start month." What I would like to do is show the start month and the 2 months that come after it and hide the rest. The other thing is that if the start month is November I only want to show the 11th and 12th months, or if the start month is December I only want to show the 12th month, it should not roll over to the next year.

```html
<?php $startMonth = "7"; ?>

<div>January</div>
<div>February</div>
<div>March</div>
<div>April</div>
<div>May</div>
<div>June</div>
<div>July</div>
<div>August</div>
<div>September</div>
<div>October</div>
<div>November</div>
<div>December</div>

<style>
div {
  display:none;
}
  div:nth-child(<?php echo $startMonth; ?>) {
    display:block;
  }
</style>
```

Would something like this be possible with PHP/CSS? I'm assuming I would have to make some calculations based on the starting month as well as implement some conditional statements to handle November/December start months.

Comment: I'd use PHP and logic to only render what is needed. I assume there are entries under these month divs. Why render more than is used?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that these divs are all contained in a single wrapping div then ...

```
div {
  display:none;
}
  div:nth-child(<?php echo $startMonth; ?>),
  div:nth-child(<?php echo $startMonth; ?>) ~ div {
    display:block;
  }
```

This displays the required nth-child plus any div children that follow it. I'd recommend applying a class rather than using `nth-child` which is quite fragile.

```css
div {
  display: none;
}

div:nth-child(7),
div:nth-child(7)~div {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>January</div>
<div>February</div>
<div>March</div>
<div>April</div>
<div>May</div>
<div>June</div>
<div>July</div>
<div>August</div>
<div>September</div>
<div>October</div>
<div>November</div>
<div>December</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I only want to show the starting month and the two months that follow(3 total) and then if the starting month is November, it would only show Nov/Dec and if it was December then it would only show December.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the specific approach you were asking for but I find this to be a better way to go about it.

```
<?php
    $startMonth = 7;
    $j = 0;
?>

<?php for ($i = $startMonth; $i <= 12; $i++): ?>
    <?php
        if ($j>2) break;
        $j++;
        $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('!m', $i);
    ?>
    <div data-month-number="<?= $i ?>">
        <h4><?= $date->format('F'); ?></h4>
    </div>
<?php endfor; ?>
```

Handles your display logic, is optimal (assume data is pulled for these months), and is much more clear than that CSS.

See it here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b9e0ee96624943cf15587030d8e82985e1540536

Answer (score -2):

Can you set a special for current div. Then try this css code `div.current + div , div.current + div + div {display:block}`. Hoping you can solve that!